# How to draw a line in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to plot a line between two points: a(xa,ya) and b(xb,yb). How can I do that in Scilab?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it convenient to do this with the `plot` command. Assemble your vertices as arrays of [x0 x1 x2 x3 ...] and [y0 y1 y2 y3 ...] and then feed them into `plot`.

So to draw a line from (0,0) to (30,40) you could use:

```
xpts = [0 30];
ypts = [0 40];

plot(xpts, ypts);
```

You can give it matrices to have it plot multiple lines in one command - type `help plot` in the console to get the specifics of the row/column conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `xpoly(x,y)` command:

**x** : vector of **xi** of points

**y** : vector of **yi** of points